# Find the values of h for which the following set of vectors is linearly independent

Tags: matrices, vectors, independence

Find the values of h for which the following set of vectors is linearly independent

```
    1   h   1
    0   1   h
    0   h   1
```

Comment: Any thoughts?  If you are stuck, try some values.  What about $h=0$?  $h=1$?  $h=2$?

Comment: What tools you know to deal with this problem?

Comment: What is meant by linear independence of a set of vectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the values of $h$ for which the determinant of the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & h & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & h\\ 0&h&1\end{pmatrix}$$ is nonzero. This determinant is $1-h^{2}$, hence all values of $h$ are allowed except $h=1$ and $h=-1$.

Comment: Thank you all of those who tried to help me, I got the answer

Answer (score 0):

solve the system $$\alpha+\beta h+\gamma=0$$
$$\beta+\gamma h=0$$
$$\beta h+\gamma=0$$

Comment: coulde you explain more pls

Comment: @user395584 Do you know how to test if a set of vectors is linearly independent?